# Multiple models with ID in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Working on this project and I am stuck again. I have a view that I need to display a menu along the side. The menu is pulled from a table. Along the side of this, I have a question that is pulled from another table. Inside of this, there will be suggestions that are yet pulled from another table. With the question, I have a couple of inputs, radio buttons, and a text box for feedback which will end up in a different table. All of this has to take place with the ID from the main table so that when the information is saved in the results table it knows what the main record it belongs too. The page can be brought up with a /Audit/302 but when you change the submenu to the next question how do you get that question and maintain the ID. For Every question, there will be an entry for that ID. I have made relationships this is what it looks like.
[image: Relationships]

August 02 2011

I have added a ViewModel that pulls a list of checkboxes from a table called Score (OK, Concern, N/A)

The page that i have is rendered with an ID it pulls a record from AuditSchedules and retrieves some info. In the Layout i also have a side menu (partial) that renders a list of actionlinks that will select different sections and a MainQuestion (partial). We work up to this point. Since i have added the viewModel to populate the checkboxes and save the text into a table with the ID of the AuditSchedule and MainQuestion. My issue is i am calling for id to select the ids from the table for the Scores and it is grabbing the id from the AuditSchedule. Giving me a no data found. 
Here is my Controller:

```
        //get
    public ActionResult _Forms(int score)
    {
        AuditFormEdit viewModel = new AuditFormEdit();
        viewModel.ScoreInstance = _db.Scores.Single(r => r.ScoreID == score);
        viewModel.InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(_db.Scores.ToList());
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    //post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _Forms(int score, AuditFormEdit viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.PopulateCheckBoxsToScores();
            _db.Entry(viewModel.ScoreInstance).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

Here is my viewModel:

```
    public class AuditFormEdit
{
    public Models.Score ScoreInstance { get; set; }

    public List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper> ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList { get; set; }

    public void InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(List<Models.Score> ScoreList)
    {
        if (this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList == null)
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList = new List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper>();

        if (ScoreList != null
            && this.ScoreInstance != null)
        {
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Clear();
            ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper spacerProductCheckBoxHelper;
            string spacerTypes =
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ScoreInstance.ScoreName) ?
                string.Empty : this.ScoreInstance.ScoreName;
            foreach (Models.Score scoreType in ScoreList)
            {
                spacerProductCheckBoxHelper = new ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(scoreType);
                if (spacerTypes.Contains(scoreType.ScoreName))
                    spacerProductCheckBoxHelper.Checked = true;
                this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Add(spacerProductCheckBoxHelper);
            }
        }
    }

    public void PopulateCheckBoxsToScores()
    {
        this.ScoreInstance.ScoreName = string.Empty;
        var scoreType = this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Where(x => x.Checked)
                              .Select<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper, string>(x => x.ScoreName)
                              .AsEnumerable();
        this.ScoreInstance.ScoreName = string.Join(", ", scoreType);
    }


    public class ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper : Models.Score
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper() : base() { }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(Models.Score scoreCard)
        {
            this.ScoreID = scoreCard.ScoreID;
            this.ScoreName = scoreCard.ScoreName;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the link and controller that pulls the page up this is the Body of the layout:

```
        public ActionResult Audit(int id)
    {
        var auditToDetail  = _db.AuditSchedules.Single(r => r.AuditScheduleID == id);
        return View(auditToDetail);
    }
```

the link looks like this:

```
/AuditSchedule/Audit/257
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

I have used a code first approach and all tables have models with the relationships called out.

thank you

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried something? Did you attempt writing some code already? Did you encounter some specific problems with your code that we could discuss here?

Comment: My question is how do i populate this view maintaining this ID. No i have not kept anything that i have tried because i really do not know where to start. I am a PHP programmer this is my first C# MVC project.

Comment: If you don't know where to start with ASP.NET MVC, I would recommend you here: http://asp.net/mvc . Then when later you have something that we could discuss don't hesitate to come back here and ask more specific question.

Comment: I take it - How do you display multiple multiple models in a view while maintaining an ID is not specific enough. I have been to that link and the tutorials add nothing to what i am trying to accomplish. I really need to know how to set up a view model to handle all of this. That is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty general - but here are some things to think about.

First, in MVC3 you typically want to strongly type your views to your models. In your case you would want a single view for each model. You don't want "multiple multiple models in a view", but rather multiple views rendered together on a single page - all linked by some common data.

One way to accomplish this would be set write a "child actions" (use:`[ChildActionOnly]` attribute) in your controller for populating each of your individual models sending them to their respective indiviudal views. You can use the [Html.RenderAction][3] function within any view to render any other view.  The easiest way to organize this is often with layouts 4 - You could render all your views using `Html.RenderAction()`, and then render your main form as the primary view (displayed in the layout with `@RenderBody()`).

To populate each of your models you will likely need to know some data (like an id), these can be stored in the ViewBag or ViewData, and passed in as objects in the `Html.RenderAction` function. (If you are using razor the call in your view might look something like:`@{Html.RenderAction("actionName", new {object1 = "xyz", object2 ="abc"});}` Just to make this clear, the logical flow will look like this

1. Populate the ViewBag with the data you will need to render your sub-views,
2. Populate your model for the main form and you call the main form's view (your primary view).
3. Your primary view defines a layout view, which in-turn calls `Html.RenderAction`, using the ViewBag data to set the appropriate objects.
4. The layout also renders the primary view as the  "body" (`@RenderBody()`).

The end result of this is views that can be [strongly typed][7] to individual views, and individual controller actions for each model. This is a good thing, because it makes your views reusable anywhere, and it isolates the logic for populating each model (because each model has its own action in the controller). If you make subsequent changes to a model, it will be easy to know which Action/Model/View needs to be modified.

Below are some resources to get you started in understanding your options for rendering multiple models on a single page. I apologize for not lacing this post with nice links to helpful items, but as a new answerer, I was limited to two... Google will have to be your guide for the others.

Hope this helps - Best of Luck!

Resources:

[Html.RenderAction and Html.Action - http://haacked.com blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)

[When to use Html.RenderPartial and Html.RenderAction in ASP.NET MVC Razor Views - http://www.arrangeactassert.com](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/)

Comment: Thanks. I have got to that point already! i have a layout that populates 1 view and 2 partial views. I used a @Html.Action to populate the partials. it was giving me errors because of the Dictionary type may differ in each. Anyway the issue i am having right now is that my modelView the way it is written uses an ID from the table and it will not work that way because this is going into a table that is empty. So i need to code it to incert a new record with the correct ID's

Comment: Glad to hear the views are working properly (the dictionary error is related to the use of Partial Views v. Views - you can avoid it by not structuring those as partials). I did have another thought - You might want to consider client-side AJAX to populate/repopulate the various views. That way, if you make a selection in one view you could reload another section (sub-view) of the page with an AJAX response, and avoid having to reload the entire page. You can trap Request.IsAjax() to decide whether to return the whole page, or just the sub-view. You can always make that an upgrade for later.